# How to store a 2D Integer array in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have this defined: `List<Integer[][]> listOfInteger= new ArrayList<>();`

How do I insert data into it?

I have tried

`listOfInteger.add(new Integer[][](1,2));`

and

```
List<Integer[][]> listOfInteger= Arrays.asList(new Integer({1, 2)});
```

But none works

Comment: Don't mix lists and arrays. Either use a `List<ArrayList<Integer>>` or `Integer [][]`

Comment: @Reimeus I have a requirement that store an 2d array element into a list. Since List<> can't take `int`, i have to make it `Integer`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html. But you should create a class IMO.

Comment: `listOfInteger.add(new Integer[][]{{1,2},{3,4}});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short way is this:

```
listOfInteger.add(new Integer[][] {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {5, 7}});
```

But you could also just create the array and then fill it one by one.

Comment: Any way to assign the value without calling the `.add` method? I am trying to initialize `listOfInteger` and give it values at the beginning of the class and outside of method blocks.

Comment: @HashMap is the list static? is this the problem? could use static initializer block `static { }` in there you can do the adds. Also works for `static final`, create temp list, add everything, assign to static final var.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the "double brace initialization"?

```
List<Integer[][]> listOfInteger= new ArrayList() {{
    add(new Integer[][] { { 3, 2 }, { 4, 2 } });
    add(new Integer[][] { { 3, 2 }, { 4, 2 } });
    add(new Integer[][] { { 3, 2 }, { 4, 2 } });
}};
```

You can do this at the class level outside of methods.

Answer (score 1):

You got confused by the dimensions you have defined an one dimensional ArrayLists which contains two-dimensional arrays as elements.

```
    List<Integer[][]> listOfInteger = new ArrayList<Integer[][]>();
    // long version
    Integer[][] array2d = new Integer[2][2];
    array2d[0][0] = 3;
    array2d[0][1] = 2;
    array2d[1][0] = 4;
    array2d[1][1] = 2;
    listOfInteger.add(array2d);
    // short version
    listOfInteger.add(new Integer[][] { { 3, 2 }, { 4, 2 } });
```

After this operations your arrayList will contain two arrays, which contain integers with the same value